How can I proxy multiple Set Cookie headers in nginx using the auth_module module?
I use auth_module to authenticate users, the api records cookies in response, which must then be returned to the client and forwarded to the next server, I did it like this:
`auth_request /internal-auth;
auth_request_set $auth_cookie $upstream_http_set_cookie;
auth_request_set $auth_header $upstream_http_authorization;
add_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;
add_header Authrozaiton $auth_header;
proxy_set_header Set-Cookie $auth_cookie;
proxy_set_header Authorization $auth_header;
`
There are no problems with one SetCookie header, but when the api records more than two cookies, these headers are combined into one and the browser cannot read and write them, only the first cookie saves.
An example of how headers are combined:
rt_box=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.SisH3lW8HoqF1iGR_ttxvEF5zbC2xihSpBndE_NYXbbbDQOheran3be7nZOmUCHDg3ETKe0hu557g7nVFmfYmPS_WweH7Yomu-NZ3gFwPhFhO4-3hIflMzMMedMw1SyeuMq6xifineAGR3np9mnmZbn94EWURWIYMZIiqNE0EUfLPMbMS3u9UVfzHdb5XlxFh2FAYuGyKUVhq2ZLyjQLq5gYK5Xn_cDSrARyDKqakb99NpcgXs1rQUVcPH0axPwTRPc5I0TS30JKxPlnVg4NOODnQetXnQkrja-TUAH5xY5iZIFjk_aT_0x2kMTTtzgFMjYltYAnaO2P2iG63UADzfmHVRPM1oHwCLY24jgVZFZBbZYPVnqNfASt6LHTnfpWk7aJ17U4LBw2WMgU5cpfbQ8nR3Qv30SYaiVbcyLImUS_FAyNm_FMwJOWgVhudZeYWbwKl6Ezks2qj1Q9JG9amwaOw27T1bBbXF4Su-1YS3xagKZiBXAgW-SJf4D7t0XJyX8UxfbIvXPGe2_uZJhAQwgPiTlvJ4xFefE8M6IKH5c4rs5bo6cOVVOzeGxZ844K00W_2VtOSFsRicN4Qa-St7RVUEOt7cZmmMfNPhBRSbyGh3tutfqD2mX6vvCSNnYTdWkIIgdHuMR-q3SXvi7KJTWIn6vzkUf_z6zHut4wz1s; expires=Sat, 20 Jul 2024 12:08:19 GMT; domain=box.localhost.ru; path=/; secure; SameSite=Lax, at_box=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.Kq4GnolnnT5OYLZTpmtyfPZN_f9j34ndFric9S-blBIcnnTUCOzyHSJD86PcpSiDXita407zR-YobHterBo8RrMzyV4r84DbpZX4ZAY7OiPksev_wMJhhQxePaDLDIOwb-gZIF29Qt2kHucMYaUSeXqHsJ2avBwY--ebCoDxR2X25iFL7e0DaHWwhOA_FC-wOeJ4_2ihnRs12_zjZS15ndxhy73WxP6tflZ6NdBd3TqAWW5gln6UIRB4bvj9xQB35zHYFNMzx3BGa9oIJIegDxpsf6MfbYUGZCS1E1vhjSGC3tkK9ll_YrzA6tvzYiNJRi1UEyUMBVRC0jO0odtRTWTnk9CDEP2iMaKQSgI_CoBqnHtZbsN2q8FqSNPlMZ-CH1mAEdzPKAa3OkJugNnNI1Ei_He8Of_O1UOK5TXAl0s8rLgnChjzs_oj2LM5jANTa-FuAYAokrozgEKRFQGanJKE8KXT45w62u-WpFsUQ7f_2_n3zY80QdGMDGKCf1DEHJQh00OUpoMAWFxRVrG3azKG2hrx8k1kSgXRNt7Vjo2rAPDH_brO4gr_aQSFWKKzym3TQgNbZrOhgjggqNbtcLVqrtAj6cAmue0vmAojcKbb5bv6E6SpktifHU8XnRCxTemJRqbdJC_GPoBMm69maMCHFxq1Rf5_QOi5wk0uvtY; expires=Sat, 13 Jul 2024 12:18:19 GMT; domain=box.localhost.ru; path=/; SameSite=Lax
How do I make sure that all Set Cookies are adequately proxied? Ideally, make sure that you do not need to bind to cookie names. Thank you very much in advance))
